# not able to enter text in text box even after switching to iframe Selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, iframe, junit, webdriver

I am trying to enter some text in text-box which is inside iframe. I am able to identify the text-box by switching to iframe, but not able to type in text.

Here, is the html code:

```
<iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" aria-describedby="cke_50" title="Rich Text Editor,missionStatementText" src="" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title data-cke-title="Rich Text Editor,missionStatementText">Rich Text Editor,missionStatementText</title>
<style data-cke-temp="1">
<link href="http://localhost:8080/sowodemo/js/ckeditor/contents.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style data-cke-temp="1">
</head>
<body class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
http://l
<br type="_moz">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

My Selenium Code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("type text");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Where are you sending the text? What is the intended element?

Comment: @Saifur there is the `body` tag - it looks like it is editable..looks like a ckeditor area.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks. I see the class name now

Comment: are you sure you are in the right iframe?

Comment: Thanx guys, just solved the problem, the page had three iframes and this was the second iframe. So, I just changed did this:                      driver.switchTo().frame(1);
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("my text"); driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Answer (score -1):

try to use actions class, we got success when we have used actions class

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the element"));
            new Actions(driver).moveToElement(we).click().sendKeys("bfsdjkf").build().perform();
```